# Are the requests in "Collections" executed in Parallel in POSTMAN`

Tags: postman

I am using the postman for the first time and need to generate multiple requests.
I added them in collections and it seems that they are executed in parallel. Whereas I want to execute them serially.

Basically depending on the response of the first request I will decide whether I have to send the second request or not?

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of Postman you are using, but collections allow you to store and group together useful requests so that you can easily find them and execute them individually.

Version 3 has a Runner Mode that is enabled when you install the Jetpacks premium extension, this has support for executing collections. Please check if you are in the Builder or Runner mode. If you are in the Runner mode, switch back to the Builder mode so you can execute requests individually again.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that really helped me.
But if I am in the runner mode, how can I ensure that request2 should be sent upon completion of request1

Comment: Ok, so that is **Request Chaining**, read more here: http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/